# Parsing Json Google GeoMaps

Tags: json

I am trying to parse a response from google maps, this is the JSON response.

```
{ "results" : [ { "address_components" : [ { "long_name" : "11", "short_name" : "11", "types" : [ "street_number" ] }, { "long_name" : "Shottermill", "short_name" : "Shottermill", "types" : [ "route" ] }, { "long_name" : "Horsham", "short_name" : "Horsham", "types" : [ "postal_town" ] }, { "long_name" : "West Sussex", "short_name" : "West Sussex", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "England", "short_name" : "England", "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "United Kingdom", "short_name" : "GB", "types" : [ "country", "political" ] }, { "long_name" : "RH12 5HG", "short_name" : "RH12 5HG", "types" : [ "postal_code" ] } ], "formatted_address" : "11 Shottermill, Horsham RH12 5HG, UK", "geometry" : { "location" : { "lat" : 51.084119, "lng" : -0.2948757 }, "location_type" : "ROOFTOP", "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 51.0854679802915, "lng" : -0.2935267197084979 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 51.0827700197085, "lng" : -0.296224680291502 } } }, "place_id" : "ChIJ0ZUiT-_rdUgRadZ4jXXzam4", "types" : [ "street_address" ] } ], "status" : "OK" }
```

If i want to for example echo out geometry( lat and lng) , how do i do this.

I have tried : ($content contains the above response)

```
$json = json_decode($content);
echo $json->results->geometry->location->lat;
echo $json->results->geometry->location->lng;
```

Comment: `results` is an array

Comment: you should iterate results, because it's an array. after that going in geometry->location->lat;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results is in an array, you should access it using by index

```
$json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
```

Check the documentation to see if the `results` array could have a length different to 1. If it is, you will need to iterate through it.